# Multiple solutions when doing ILP

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pulp

Currently I'm using `PuLP` to solve a maximization problem.  It works fine, but I'd like to be able to get the N-best solutions instead of just one.  Is there a way to do this in `PuLP` or any other free/Python solution?  I toyed with the idea of just randomly picking some of the variables from the optimal solution and throwing them out and re-running, but this seems like a total hack.

Comment: is there any way to find all integer solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out how (by RTFM) to get multiple soutions.  In my code I essentially have:

```
number_unique = 1  # The number of variables that should be unique between runs

model += objective
model += constraint1
model += constraint2
model += constraint3

for i in range(1,5):
    model.solve()
    selected_vars = []
    for p in vars:
         if p_vars[p].value() != 0:
             selected_vars.append(p)
    print_results()

    # Add a new constraint that the sum of all of the variables should
    # not total up to what I'm looking for (effectively making unique solutions)
    model += sum([p_vars[p] for p in selected_vars]) <= 10 - number_unique
```

This works great, but I've realized that I really do need to go the random route.  I've got 10 different variables and by only throwing out a couple of them, my solutions tend to have the same heavy weighted  vars in all the permutations (which is to be expected).

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is fast to solve, you can try to limit the objective from above step by step. For examle, if the objective value of the optimal solution is `X`, try to re-run the problem with an additional constraint:

```
problem += objective <= X - eps, ""
```

where the reduction step `eps` depends on your knowledge of the problem.

Of course, if you just pick some `eps` blindly and get a solution, you don't know if the solution is the 2nd best, 10th best or 1000-th best ...  But you can do some systematic search (binary, grid) on the `eps` parameter (if the problem is really fast to solve).